# Caught and error in adding UL using javascript to HTML in div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create UL element using JavaScript and adding it to div in html page but the problem is when I'm appending the UL to a div in html. I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I tried appending it to body and header and it works but not in a div element.

Thank you!

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CodeError</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class='.main'></div>
    </header>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
const body = document.querySelector('.main');

const ul = document.createElement('ul');
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = 'Nico';
ul.appendChild(li);
body.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: Protip: Tags and elements are not the same thing. A tag is markup in your text file. An element is part of the document model. It's best to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is:

```
<div class='.main'></div>
```

Your JS code is looking for an element with class 'main', the dot represents the fact that it's a class. Your actual class name should be 'main', not '.main', so:

```
<div class='main'></div>
```

The error is thrown by this line:

```
body.appendChild(ul);
```

Because `body` is null at this point. Because this line:

```
const body = document.querySelector('.main');
```

Fails to find an element with `class='main'`, because currently you have `class='.main'`.

Answer (score 2):

`CSS` class name Naming rules:

- Must begin with a letter `A-Z` or `a-z`
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
  and underscores ("_")

Change This:

```
<div class='.main'></div>
```

To This:

```
<div class='main'></div>
```